# I am building a website using ASP.Net & I encountered an 'invalid object name' error as shown. What is the reason behind this error?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm building a small website using ASP.Net & I encountered the following error.

**Code**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace WebApplication_Exam_Website
{
    public partial class OnlineAssessment : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Myconnection"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
                string sqlquery = "select * from questionnaire";
                sqlconn.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
                SqlDataAdapter sdr = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sdr.Fill(dt);
                Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
                Repeater1.DataBind();
                sqlconn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error @Line 26: sdr.Fill(dt);**:

Invalid object name 'questionnaire'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'questionnaire'.

Why am I getting this error?

P.S.: 'questionnaire' is the name of the SQL table I've created.

Connection string-->

```
<add name="Myconnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\utopia\Desktop\Project\Us.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: Can you also let us know the connection string you are using

Comment: possibly because there is no table by that name in the current schema?

Comment: Connection String --><add name="Myconnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\utopia\Desktop\Project\Us.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: "create table questionnaire" --> questionnaire is the table name & I've included the same in my code.

Comment: Either you've created the table in a different database to the one you're connecting to, or it's in a different schema. Try specifying the schema name explicitly on both the `create table` and `select` commands - `dbo.questionnaire`.

Comment: Also, the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects need to be wrapped in `using` blocks: [using statement (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)